# Facebook share only certain div

Tags: php, facebook

So I have the following code for facebook share.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post_share_facebook" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,                 '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=220,width=600');return false;">
<i class="icon-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

Right now, when the share button is clicked, the whole snapshot of the page is shown on the share window. 
On a php file where this share button is located, I have a specific `div` which I want to show on the Facebook share window instead of the whole snapshot of the page.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking, I have same qus. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445832/share-my-feed-in-socialengine-framework-to-facebook-using-facebook-share-button

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its possible that way, you can try `<?php the_permalink(); ?>#your_div_id`

Another alternate would be using [open graph](http://ogp.me/)